# How to update data according to previous query result in php

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I want to update data according previous query result.

My first query return as GRN number and I want to **update** these GRN number into another table at the same time.

Here is my code :

```
$sqlsel = "SELECT `grn` FROM `tblstudent` WHERE  `classname` = '$class' AND `division` = '$division'";
$queryselgrn = mysql_query($sqlsel);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryselgrn)) {
    $grn = array();
    //$grn = $row["grn"]; 
    $grn = $row['grn'];
}

$grn = explode("-",$grn);
$j = 1;

foreach($grn as $v) {
    $j = $v;

    echo $j;
    $sqlup  = "UPDATE `tblhomeworkstatus` SET `studentid`='$j' WHERE `hwid` ='$hwid'";
    $j++;
    $queryup = mysql_query($sqlup);
}

if(!$query and !$queryins) {
    die('not inserted:' .mysql_error());
} else {
     echo "inserted!";
}
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: only last value is updated, instead i want to update all values returns in result.

Comment: Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), or change `$row['grn']`  to `$row['0']`

Comment: ok thanks for reply,

Comment: declare the array out of the while loop.

Comment: no change , only one value updated, i tried $row[0] but it gives undefined index error!

Comment: why are you exploding the array value? see the value of `$grn` by using `var_dump($grn)` after the while loop.

Comment: no change only one value returns , in table there are 10 matching result found , but i got only one

Comment: Check `$grn` value using `var_dump($grn)`

Comment: it gives result but on update single value is updating, instead i want to update all value